# Toggle between Front and Back camera not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have written a code in React js which toggles the front and back camera but it is not working properly.

```
import { useEffect,useRef } from "react"
import { useState } from "react"
export default function App(){
   const [strm,setStrm]=useState(null)
   const [cam,setCam]=useState(true)
   const myVdo=useRef(null)
   useEffect(()=>{
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video:{facingMode:'user'},audio:true})
    .then((stream)=>{
      setStrm(stream)
    })
   },[])
   useEffect(()=>{
    myVdo.current.srcObject=strm
   },[strm])
   const Flip=(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault()
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video:{facingMode:cam?'environment':'user'},audio:true})
    .then((s)=>{
      setStrm(s)
      setCam(!cam)
    })
   }
   return(
    <>
    <video autoPlay ref={myVdo}/>
    <button onClick={Flip}>Flip</button>
    </>
   )
}
```

Please help me to get rid of this issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't reproduced it, but you can simplify like this

```
const [strm, setStrm] = useState(null);
  const [cam, setCam] = useState(true);
  const myVdo = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    navigator.mediaDevices
      .getUserMedia({ video: { facingMode: cam ? "user" : "environment" }, audio: true })
      .then((stream) => {
        setStrm(stream);
      });
  }, [cam]);

  useEffect(() => {
    myVdo.current.srcObject = strm;
  }, [strm]);

  const flip = () => {
    setCam(!cam);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <video autoPlay ref={myVdo} />
      <button onClick={flip}>Flip</button>
    </>
  );
```

Here I am ading a dependency for cam in the first useEffect so that after each flip, it changes the facingMode.

Comment: It still not working :( user->environment->blank->environment->blank->environment.......